# I cannot use html tags in .js file (jsx code)

Tags: reactjs

[the space in tag is auto generated while saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEs40.png)I am new to react just started created a file with index.html and app.js .I have included react scripts in index.html .but I cannot use html tags in .js file (jsx code) throws error.  babel installed .what to do???

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Answer (score -1):

You need to import React framework to have access to jsx, and the ReactDOM:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

This is how you call them:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Notice I have an `<App />` component, which means I also had to import it from the `App.js`, so what you're seeing right now is the `index.js` or whatever you wanna call it.

Without them it's **plain javascript**. I'd suggest using `npx create-react-app` cuz it creates this boilerplate for you.

Comment: Actually I am learning from udemy I have included react and reactdom scripts .and tested in developer tools the react and reactdom is installed